# Draw several polygons on top of matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot some data where there was a stimulus given every 3000s for 1500s, 5 times.
I would like to plot my signal and in the background display when the stimulus was given.
For instance like this, here colored in red:
[image]

At the moment my code looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df=pd.read_csv('file.csv')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))
df.plot(ax=ax)

#draw verticle lines (I can do this in one line)
ax.vlines(np.arange(0, len(df), 30*50), 0, 1, transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), colors='r', alpha=0.5)

#draw polygons (I know only how to write one line per polygon)
ax.axvspan(0, 1500, 0, 1, color='red', alpha=0.4)
ax.axvspan(3000, 4500, 0, 1, color='red', alpha=0.4)
ax.axvspan(6000, 7500, 0, 1, color='red', alpha=0.4)
ax.axvspan(9000, 10500, 0, 1, color='red', alpha=0.4)
ax.axvspan(12000, 13500, 0, 1, color='red', alpha=0.4)

ax.set_xlim([0, len(activity)])
ax.set_ylabel('Normalised Intensity (a.u)')
ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.show()
```

Is there a smarter way of drawing the polygons? Ideally similar to ax.vlines().
I could write a for loop for each axvspan() but I would prefer if there is some function that works with np.arange() similar to ax.vlines().

Thank you very much!

Comment: `for x in range(0, 12001, 3000): ax.axvspan(x, x+1500, 0, 1, color='red', alpha=0.4)`

Comment: Hi, Thank you. This is indeed better. But I was wondering if there is a way of doing it without a for loop or without defining an extra function. In the case of drawing lines I can go with ax.vlines(np.arange(0, len(df), 30*50), 0, 1, transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), colors='r', alpha=0.5). But for polygons it seems one needs a for loop or a separate function, correct? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward.

```py
def plot_stimuli(ax, start, number:int, step, **kwargs):
    for _ in range(number):
        ax.axvspan(start, start+step, 0, 1, **kwargs)
        start += 2*step

plot_stimuli(ax, 0, len(df), 30*50, color='red', alpha=0.4)
```

It's simple because the width of the polygons is the same as the gap between them. If you need to separate width and gap, we can do that with a few minor changes.

Comment: Hello, Thanks. That is indeed better. I guess matplotlib does not have a function to do that, like in ax.vlines(np.arange(0, len(df), 30*50), 0, 1, transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), colors='r', alpha=0.5). Right? So there is no way of doing it without defining an extra function. Correct?